# Django 1.8 template's URL tag TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to learn how to use the Django template's URL tag to make my code more generic, but I am having some exception being raised.

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

Here is my global urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

Here is my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
}
```

And here is one template where I am trying to use the feature.

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
  <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.content }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/app/polls/views.py" in index
  11.     return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  217.                             nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  433.             self._populate()
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  308.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  338.             self._populate()
File "/home/polydo_s/Projects/Modeling/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  285.         for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
```

I have been looking for this for hours, and I seem to follow all the guidelines to make this work, but of course something must be wrong.

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the stack trace so that we know this exception is not raised in `views.detail`?

Comment: Not related, but you forgot `namespace="polls"` in your master `urls.py`. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `urlpatterns` as a `set` - `{` and `}`. You need a `list` - `[` and `]`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

Comment: Oh for real. I am really new to Django, but I did not see that coming.
Big thanks to you because I could literally have searched this for AGES.

Comment: @SwannPolydor you're welcome. Look back at my early questions (also Django related) for a laugh, and you'll feel a lot better.

Comment: That's not a `dict`, it's a `set`. `{0: 1, 2: 3}` will give you a `dict`, but using single values like in `{0, 2}` gives you a set.

Comment: @Matthias ah yes, I forgot. Thanks. I've updated the answer.